# Logging the same message to two different logger instances python

Tags: python, logging

Looking for some confirmation if I have checked all the documentation correctly and some functionality is in non-existence w.r.t. to `logging` in Python.

Having two instances of a logger in Python. Now I would log the same message to both logger1 and logger2 instances.

```
import logging
logger1 = logging.getLogger('logger1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('logger2')
```

Is there some function of `logging` which supports this? Or should I simply define variable or create my own function or to log to both instances?

```
msg = "some log message..."
logger1.info(msg)
logger2.info(msg)
```

What I maybe expected is a (out of the box) functionality which provides
`logging.info([logger1,logger2],msg)` or `logger1.logger2.info(msg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do

```
list(map(lambda logger:logger.info(msg),[logger1,logger2]))
```